# Is probability heavily related to graph theory?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, advice

Can one take a probability elective course without taking any graph theory or advanced combinatorics class before?

lets assume that one knows already the basic difference between variation, combination and permutations.

As I found them in the recommended prerequisites for probability theory.

Comment: Are you talking about school or university course?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann Univerisity

Comment: Permutations, combination etc. are related to elementary probability. Have you heard about random variables, distributons?

Comment: Probability isn't heavily related to graph theory. So no, you can take a lot  of courses on probability without graph theory. Usually, you get all the combinatorics you need in the probability course as well.

Comment: If you want to study probability then don't worry at all about a lack in your knowledge that concerns graph theory. Combinatorics will show up, but an advanced class in it is redundant. It will more likely turn out to be a nice meeting with combinatorics.